# How to simulate typing and change input value in Chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, input, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, javascript-objects

I need a way to change the value of the input field with my new value

I tried `input.value` didn't work.
Tried this function:

```
  function simulateTyping(element, value, i) {
    i === 0 && element.setAttribute("value", value);
    i === 0 && (element.value = "");

    if (i < value.length) {
      element.value += value.charAt(i);
      element.dispatchEvent(
        new Event("textInput", {
          data: value.charAt(i),
          inputType: "textInput",
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        })
      );
      element.dispatchEvent(
        new Event("input", {
          bubbles: true,
          data: value.charAt(i),
          cancelable: true,
        })
      );
      setTimeout(simulateTyping.bind(this, element, value, i + 1), 10);
    } else {
      element.dispatchEvent(
        new Event("change", {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        })
      );
      element.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur", { bubbles: true }));
      var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
      evt.initEvent("keyup", true, true);
      element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  }
```

This function changed the value but suddenly the website is changing the value but If I type the number with my keyboard  the website didn't change the value .

I think there is something more which we need to find to actually simulate real keypress
This is the website
https://tibiablackjack.com/crash

Video demo
https://www.loom.com/share/cb568c04ac85427395c2f0e1481c7fb9